# Rails 4 Deep Nested Association for Selecting from Collection of Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best way to do this in Rails 4?

I have products. Products belong to a Category, like "Shirt." A Category has many Properties, like "Size." Properties have many PropertyValues, like "Small," "Medium," etc.

The User needs to be able to assign a Product to a Category, and then set the Property Value for a Property.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many : properties    

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :property_values

class PropertyValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
```

So if I am to keep track of the values that a user selects for her or his product's particular category property, what kind of association and set up to use?

I have considered the scenario of creating for Product and PropertyValue a has_many, :through => association via a ProductAttribute join model, and lookup/set selected PropertyValues via creating and/or removing a join table record. Hence:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :product_attributes
  belongs_to :property_value, :through => :product_attribute

class PropertyValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :product_attributes
  has_many :products, :through => :product_attributes

class ProductAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :property_value
```

Alternatively, I could create a Product and Property has_many, :through => association via a ProductAttribute join model. From there, I could store the selected PropertyValue's text/value in a field on the join table, or I could go one step further and create for ProductAttribute a belongs_to association with PropertyValue and keep track which value is selected via this one to many association. Hence:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :product_attributes
  belongs_to :property, :through => :product_attribute

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :property_values
  has_many :product_attributes
  has_many :products, :through => :product_attributes

class ProductAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :property_value

class PropertyValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :product_attributes
```

Not sure how viable these approaches are and which one to take if any, or if there is otherwise a best practice for this kind of scenario that I don't understand.

Comment: if you have Property with many attributes and values how do you plan to use it?

Comment: 1. The category is defined, and the user adds attributes. The values for each attribute are then also defined by the user. 2. A product is created. Upon selecting a product's category association, a user can then also view all the associated attributes and their values, and select one of the values that apply, like "Small" for "Size" if "Shirt" category is selected. More specifically -  I would like to have a select field with all of the available values from which the user can choose for the product's attribute.